# How to reuse one association in another in Rails 4.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model `User`.
I have the following associations:

```
has_many :user_schools
has_many :schools, through: :user_schools, source: :school
has_many :active_schools, -> {where(active: true)}, through: :user_schools, source: :school
```

How can I reuse `:schools` to write the association for `:active_schools` without repeating the following:

```
through: :user_schools, source: :school
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need it for is the query method, just define a scope on `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active_schools, -> { schools.where(active: true) }
end
```

and use it like this

```
user.active_schools
```

or define a scope on `School`

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end
```

and use it like this

```
user.schools.active
```

or even do both and use the scope on `School` in the scope on `User`.

Comment: I think it should be `where(active: true)`, not `schools.where(active: true)`.

Comment: @Dave, I wanted to define the `schools.active` in the form of an association. This is definitely a commonly used practice but in case I want to chain multiple method calls it's better to make a function and I wanted the function to be defined in terms of an association.